# How to re-execute the query script of an App Maker Datasource

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-app-maker

### Goal

Use App Maker to collect User Birthdays and display only the Birthdays this Month.

### Issue

I have a data model, `persons`. In that model are two Datasources, the default `persons` and a second `birthdaysThisMonth`. The datasource query script in `birthdaysThisMonth` properly runs and returns only the birthdays this month from the `persons` model.

However, when I change a birthdate in the `persons` datasource, the `birthdaysThisMonth` datasource remains unchanged, e.g., the Query script in `birthdaysThisMonth` is not *re-executed*.

To change the birthdate, I select a new date from the date picker, and the new value is shown in a table. I am not using a submit button, I see the change when the date picker looses focus.

### What I've Tried

This script is executed as a *Query script* in the `birthdaysThisMonth` datasource *which is **not** set to `Manual save mode`*. It returns the records I want.

```
function setBirthdays() {
  var calcRecords = [];
  var personsRecords = app.models.persons.newQuery().run();
  for (i=0; i<personsRecords.length; i++) {
    var id = app.models.persons.newQuery().filters.Id._equals = i;
    if (personsRecords[i].birthdate.getMonth() == thisMonth())  {
      var calcRecord = app.models.persons.newRecord();
      calcRecord.emailSecondary = personsRecords[i].emailSecondary;
      calcRecord.birthdate = personsRecords[I].birthdate;
      calcRecord.Id = personsRecords[i].Id;
      calcRecords.push(calcRecord);
    }
  }
  return calcRecords;
}
```

### Question

How do I re-execute the query script in `birthdaysThisMonth` when the data in `persons` has been updated. How do I trigger the query so it reevaluates the data in `persons` and filters accordingly.

Using Events and `onAfterSave` seems promising, but I haven't found an example of this.

### BTW

I'd like this work to happen on the server side if possible.

Comment: You are missing crucial information for a robust answer. How are you changing the birthdate? I assume you are using a DateBox widget in the client side, right? In the client side you can use client scripting to reload the datasource... https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/client#DataSource

Comment: Unfortunately you can't use server events like onAfterSave to trigger reloading a datasource on the client, so your proposed solution won't work. It would seem that your only possible solution would be to make your persons datasource a manual save datasource, in the form where you change the birth date you will need a 'Save' button that calls widget.datasource.saveChanges() and in that function incorporate a callback that will reload your birthdaysThisMonth datasource.

Comment: Markus, I hadn't considered how App Maker was using the client to so show this data, and the Client doesn't send db updates every time a field changes. Makes sense that the submit button should be used to message the server and trigger the Query scripts.

Comment: Morfinsimo and Markus, what works for me is to set the datasource to Manual save mode, and use a Button to update the datasource, which triggers the Query Script.

Comment: My mistake was thinking that changing a form-field's value might trigger the Model's Datasource Query script.

More importantly, I didn't understand that datasources _should_ be accessed through the client (see documentation).

Perhaps my goal of creating a Query script (server side) that keeps birthdate records filtered by `thisMonth()` is misguided. I'm starting to think I need the client's table widget to query the model each time it needs to display these filtered records, instead of poking the server to update birthdates on the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Markus Malessa's comment for the answer.

> Unfortunately you can't use server events like onAfterSave to trigger reloading a datasource on the client, so your proposed solution won't work. It would seem that your only possible solution would be to make your persons datasource a manual save datasource, in the form where you change the birth date you will need a 'Save' button that calls widget.datasource.saveChanges() and in that function incorporate a callback that will reload your birthdaysThisMonth datasource

The way I'm attempting to push/pull data isn't great. Looks like Manual Mode provides the types of features I need.